# using promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        //asynchronous part

        var dom_domain_name_encoded;
        chrome.tabs.query({ 
            "active": true,
            "currentWindow": true,
            "status": "complete",
            "windowType": "normal"
        }, function (tabs) {
            for (tab in tabs) {
                dom_domain_name_encoded=tabs[tab].url;
                dom_domain_name_encoded = encodeURIComponent(dom_domain_name_encoded);
                console.log(dom_domain_name_encoded);
                // return dom_domain_name_encoded;
            }
        });
        //asynchronous part ends here.

        if (dom_domain_name_encoded) {
            console.log("encoded and returning");
            resolve(dom_domain_name_encoded);
        }
        else {
            console.log("error");
            reject(Error("It broke"));
        }
    });

    promise.then(
        function(dom_domain_name_encoded) {
            console.log(dom_domain_name_encoded);
        }
    ).catch(
        function(reason) {
            console.log("promise not working");
        }
    );
```

I created a promise in which a chrome.tabs function is getting executed. Being an asynchronous function I put it there. It fetched the url of the current tab and passes it to the .then method. Now as in the reference for promises, I would expect it to run the .then method but something is going wrong and "error" is what i am getting in console.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You should resolve the promise in the asynchronous callback, because that's what asynchronous means: the callback is executed after the parent code completes. Don't forget to study how the classic asynchronous callbacks work because promises are just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yeah it worked. thank you :)